# error: Must contain an `adapter` key referencing the adapter to use

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I'm doing authority management.I created another table for admin in db and created a data inf. But when I searched for it that it didn't work.

Here is the code in api/controllers/AdminController.js

```
checkUN: function(req, res) {
    var name = req.param('name');

    Admin.find({
        name: name
    }).exec(function findOneCB(err, admins) {
        // print in terminal correctly
        console.log('name:'+name);

        if (err) {
            // console.log('err');
            // did not enter this judgment
            // res.redirect('admin/login');
            return res.json({
              error: 'This user name does not exist'
            });
        }
        // return res.view("user/addUser", {
        //     admins: admins
        // });
    });
},
```

There was no error inf in terminal or browser console.Then I added the `connection` and `tableName` for each models.

Here is the code in api/models/Admin.js

```
module.exports = {
  connection: 'applicationform',
  tableName: 'Admin',
  attributes: {
    name: {
      type: 'string'
    },
    password: {
      type: 'string'
    },
    email: {
      type: 'string'
    },
    createdAt: {
      type: 'datetime',
      defaultsTo: function (){ return new Date(); }
    },
    updatedAt: {
      type: 'datetime',
      defaultsTo: function (){ return new Date(); }
    }
   }
  };
```

Here is the error inf in terminal:

> error: In model (admin), invalid connection :: applicationform
>   error: Must contain an `adapter` key referencing the adapter to use.

This is my config/connections.js code.

```
mysql: {
    adapter   : 'sails-mysql',
    host      : 'localhost',
    port      : 3306,
    user      : 'root',
    password  : '1',
    database  : 'applicationform'
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of your connection is `mysql`, not `applicationform`, which is the database name.

Replace `applicationform` with `mysql` as the `connection` in your model definition and it should work.

Comment: I don't think you'll get an error, but an empty array as the result in case of no results being found for your query